# How can I query for a list of specific road types in the same Overpass query?

Tags: query, overpass-api

I'm trying to query for a number of specific road types in the same request, and I can't get the syntax right at all.

Can anyone alter the following query to select "motorway", "trunk" and "primary" roads?

```
[timeout:25];
way["highway"="motorway"](53.5084,-2.9916,53.6,-2.8);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[timeout:25][bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
  way["highway"="motorway"];
  way["highway"="trunk"];
  way["highway"="primary"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

See it on overpass-turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/aTL

Comment: On overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/aT3 , but note you'll also probably want motorway_link, primary_link and trunk_link .

Comment: You can also replace the repeated `({{bbox}}` by a global bbox. The first line would then read: `[timeout:25][bbox:{{bbox}}];` while the other row looks like: `way["highway"="motorway"];`

Comment: For the sake of completeness: you can of course also use regular expressions: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/aTO